# How can I fill up my toilet model with water?

Tags: modeling

I have a toilet mesh here. I'm trying to find a way to fill up my toilet bowl with water. Any suggestions? I'll give two pictures of the mesh.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Edit Mode select an Edge Loop at a location where you want the top of the water to be.

[image]

Duplicate it <kbd>SHFT</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> Then separate it by pressing <kbd>P</kbd> > Selection.

<kbd>TAB</kbd> into Object Mode and select the object you just created (I hid the other objects).

<kbd>TAB</kbd>  into Edit Mode and Extrude these vertices inward as in the image<kbd>E</kbd>  <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>SHFT</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>

[image]

Select all of the vertices *except* the outer edge and move them down a bit <kbd>G</kbd> <kbd>Z</kbd> This creates the "meniscus".

[image]

You will want a Subsurf Modifier and Smooth Shading.

Here is my Node Setup for the material.

[image: Nodes]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

From what I understood,you can add a plane inside toilet bowl and give it water texture like this:[image]

Comment: I'll try it, but I can't seem to get a water texture. I'm completely new at water in Blender.

Comment: You will have to create your own water texture. I would recommend looking up a few videos on water on youtube. Also maybe add some displacement to the plane.

Comment: @Matthew Lee ...water texture? don't you just need a transparent material with some surface light reflection?

Comment: @m.ardito I will try all of these answers. Thank you for answering.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MJD-qL77Cug, and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vfRlLbhlm4o are two pretty good tutorials if you're interested.